# Selenium - Edge - How to start a webdriver session with work profile?

Tags: selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation, selenium-edgedriver

My application does not have a login page to get authenticated. It uses my organizational email id (SSO) to authenticate my access to the application. I am using Version 80.0.361.66 (Official build) (64-bit) of Microsoft Edge.

```
driver = webdriver.Edge()
driver.maximize_window()
```

selenium version - selenium==**3.141.0**

This edge session does not use my work profile . It opens a new session because of which my work profile is not loaded and my access to the application is denied. However, I did try to update the version of selenium to use EdgeOptions. But, that didn't work as well. Below is the code :

```
options = webdriver.EdgeOptions() 
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Ajmal.Moideen\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Edge\\User Data") 
driver = webdriver.Edge(options=options) 
driver.maximize_window()
```

selenium version=**4.0.0a3**

Comment: Describe your SSO authentication process.  Do you use a certificate or a password to login from a fresh browser?

Comment: Not entirely sure, but I'm interpreting https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium#download-a-webdriver-language-binding to mean that you need `web driver.EdgeOptions(false)` to correctly initialise the Chromium version of edge.

Comment: Thanks @MatthiasWinkelmann . I tried that as well now. However, the edge driver is not getting configured with the configuration in options

Comment: Basically, the SSO authentication uses a bearer token passed in the authorization header. @pcalkins

Comment: `options = webdriver.EdgeOptions(is_legacy=False)
 options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Ajmal.Moideen\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Edge\\User Data")
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Edge(options=options)`

I tried adding a start-maximized argument to check if driver was accepting the options list. The browser was not getting maximized.

Comment: the token is usually set after login.  What is the method of login for the auth server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I got it to work - I am using Chromium Edge 85.0.564.51 with Selenium 3.141.0.

Selenium 3.141.0 from pip doesn't seem to support new Chromium-based Edge Webdriver, but Microsoft supplies it in their [`msedge-selenium-tools` package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium?tabs=python#download-a-webdriver-language-binding) ([better documentation here](https://github.com/microsoft/edge-selenium-tools)) as mentioned by Matthias' comment on your question.

First, grab the Chromium Edge webdriver [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/#downloads) - get the version that matches your version of Edge (go to `chrome:version` in Edge to see what version you are running). Put the webdriver somewhere convenient, you need to set `driverpath` below to point to it.

Install the pip packages:

```sh
pip install msedge-selenium-tools selenium==3.141
```

In your code, import the `msedge-selenium-tools` Webdriver and Options modules and build the webdriver as shown:

```py
from msedge.selenium_tools import Edge, EdgeOptions

...

options = EdgeOptions()
options.use_chromium = True
options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\YOUR-USERNAME\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Edge\\User Data")
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
driverpath = 'msedgedriver.exe'

driver = Edge(driverpath, options=options)
```

Voilà, that should do the trick.

P.S.: Even though `chrome:version` will show your Profile path with a trailing `\Default`, don't include that in your `--user-data-dir` argument above, since the driver seems to append `\Default` to the end.